# New file creation when current file exceeds certain size

Tags: c#, log4net

Refered the post 
[Why is log4net creating two separate log files when using RollingFileAppender?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18530738/why-is-log4net-creating-two-separate-log-files-when-using-rollingfileappender/18532788#18532788)

I want to know if creation of new log files whe current file exceeds certain size is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at RollingFileAppender in the [log4net config examples](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html). The example given there does have a max file size, and a new file is generated once the old one hits the cap.

```
<appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="log.txt" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <rollingStyle value="Size" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
    <maximumFileSize value="100KB" />
    <staticLogFileName value="true" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
</appender>
```

Comment: Will the new file have the timestamp by default?

Comment: This example just uses numbers, but they've got a few other examples on that page. Their documentation and examples aren't always the greatest, but I'm sure a combination of those examples will get you what you need.

Comment: I understand. But only seen that the file names will be created in file.txt1, file.txt2 fashion. Is there anyway to create that as file1.txt, file2.txt? :(

Comment: No idea - I'd guess no, but you can always try deriving from `RollingFileAppender` and building your own appender class. `log4net` is pretty open, so I would expect that you could override a few methods to make that happpen.

Comment: To keep the file extension as txt set [PreserveLogFileNameExtension](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender.PreserveLogFileNameExtension.html) to `true`.